# Как запустить отправку формы после получения AJAX - ответа от сервера

Tags: jquery, ajax, form

Здравствуйте, может кто подскажет.
Мне нужно обновить поля формы перед отправкой. Для этого формирую ajax-запрос, но форма не дожидаясь ответа делает отправку полей.

Как заставить форму сделать отправку только после получения ответ от сервера?

Или, как вариант, отменить `event.preventDefault()` (если вызван) и продолжить выполнение формы?

```
$( "#upload" ).submit(function( event ) {
        $.post(
            "script_ajax.php",
            {
                'arRoles'               : $arRoles,
                'arTranslationCanals'   : $arTranslationCanals,
                'arAnonses'             : $arAnonses,
                'arMediaFile'           : $arMediaFile,
            },
            onAjaxComplIb
        );
//  event.preventDefault();
});
function onAjaxComplIb(data){
   //какая-то логика которая добавляет полученное значение в нужные инпуты 
}
```

Заранее, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял то достаточно на сабмит отправить запрос куда вам нужно, и в ответе этого аякс запроса уже отправлять ваш запрос и измененными данными, как то так думаю это должно выглядеть:

```
$(document)on('submit', '#upload', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {param1: 'value1'},
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        if (response.ok == true) {
            //Запускаете вашу отправку
            $.post(
                "script_ajax.php",
                {
                    'arRoles'               : $arRoles,
                    'arTranslationCanals'   : $arTranslationCanals,
                    'arAnonses'             : $arAnonses,
                    'arMediaFile'           : $arMediaFile,
                },
                onAjaxComplIb
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Но дело в том что мне все это нужно в разрезе Bitrix. Тоесть я не знаю куда и как отправляется форм. Мне нужно сказать скрипту : "пока не получил ответ от сервера - остановись (или  отмени отправку event.preventDefault()", а как только что-то получил то продолжи работу в штатном режиме.